# iPhone App - dismissing modal view controller doesn't dealloc it

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (call it NumberTwo) which I presented as a modal view controller from another UIViewController (call it NumberOne). NumberTwo contains a touchesBegan method which listens for touches, and it also has an accelerometer method which listens for device orientation changes in the x, y, or z direction. NumberTwo has a button called "Done" which, when tapped, dismisses itself as a modal view controller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

But it seems as though it's still listening for touches, and it's still listening for accelerations. How can I completely free up NumberTwo when I dismiss it? I tried adding a release call as follows:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[self release];
```

but that caused a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you release the controller after you presented it?  E.g. in your method in NumberOneController that presents it, do you have something like:

```
NumberTwoController * controller = [NumberTwoController alloc] init];
// do stuff to config controller
[self presentModalViewController: controller];
[controller release];
```

Unless you want to hang on to `NumberTwoController` for re-use, this would be the usual pattern. The `presentModalViewController` method ensures that the controller is retained while it's in use. It should then get tidied up when, within `NumberTwoController`, you call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: NO]`.

Comment: What if you're using ARC? How do you destroy the viewController after dismissing?

Comment: If you're using ARC then the compiler will (in effect) insert the [controller release] after the controller has been presented modally. No need to take any steps on dismissal - iOS will make sure the controller is released in these circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar issue that plagued me for days. It turned out that my view controller class wasn't being deallocated when I dismissed it because that view controller had an active NSTimer that wasn't being invalidated (stopped). I was able to kill the timer in viewDidDisappear.

Comment: How did you find out? I mean is there something in Instruments that helps in this situation or was it just you re-reading your code?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding -- unfortunately, it was just re-reading my code that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are releasing everything you use when you finish with it; The `dealloc` method is only called when the `UIViewController` and all of its properties/objects are no longer in use. Never use `[self release];` you need to release it from the view controller that created it after you are finished with it.